# html tree from xml with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new with xml transformation to html. I have a xml file with a simple file/folder structure.

```
<structure>
    <container>
        <name>Container A</name>
        <item>
            <name>Item A</name>
        </item>
        <container>
            <name>Container A A</name>
            <item>
                <name>Item B</name>
            </item>
            <item>
                <name>Item A B</name>
            </item>
        </container>
    </container>
    <container>
        <name>Container B</name>
        <item>
            <name>Item C</name>
        </item>
    </container>
    <item>
        <name>Item X</name>
    </item>
</structure>
```

I want to have a html tree using bullet list tags. The container element can have sub containers and items within, the item element can not have any other elements. Maybe the following html snippet would give an overview about the result.

```
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="container">Container A</div>
            <ul>
                <li>...</li>
                <li>
                    <div class="item">Item A</div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>...</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>Container A A</div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>...</li>
                        <li>
                            <div>Item B</div>
                            <ul>
                                <li>...</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div>Item A B</div>
                            <ul>
                                <li>...</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>Container B</div>
            <ul>
                <li>...</li>
                <li>
                    <div>Item C</div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>...</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>Item X</div>
            <ul>
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

How can I use client side only xslt transformation to get the result? Or is there a better way to achieve the goal?

Mike

Comment: please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The following solution does not output the exact destination XML. It is rather an educated guessing of what I think you want:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="text()" />

    <xsl:template match="structure">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="container|item">
        <li>
            <div class="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="name" />
            </div>
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </ul>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="container">Container A</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="item">Item A</div>
                <ul/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="container">Container A A</div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="item">Item B</div>
                        <ul/>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="item">Item A B</div>
                        <ul/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="container">Container B</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="item">Item C</div>
                <ul/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item">Item X</div>
        <ul/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This should suffice as a starting point to create an XSLT fully compliant with your expectations.